# $(\mu,P,T)$ pseudo-ensemble: why is it not a proper thermodynamic ensemble?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

While teaching statistical mechanics, and describing the common thermodynamic ensembles (microcanonical, canonical, grand canonical), I usually give a line on why there can be no $(\mu, P, T)$ thermodynamic ensemble ($\mu$ being the chemical potential, $P$ being the pressure, and $T$ being the temperature). My usual explanation is a handwaving that all of the control parameters would be intensive, which leaves all the extensive conjugated parameters unbounded, and you can't write your sums and integrals anymore.

However, I have always felt uneasy because:

1. I never was able to properly convince myself where exactly the problem arose in a formal derivation of the ensemble (I am a chemist and as such, my learning of statistical mechanics didn't dwell on formal derivations).
2. I know that the $(\mu, P, T)$ can actually be used for example for numerical simulations, if you rely on limited sampling to keep you out of harm's way (see, for example, [F. A. Escobedo, *J. Chem. Phys.*, 1998](http://dx.doi.org/doi:10.1063/1.476429)). (Be sure to call it a *pseudo-ensemble* if you want to publish it, though.)

So, I would like to ask how to address point #1 above: **how can you properly demonstrate how chaos would arise from the equations of statistical mechanisms if one defines a $(\mu, P, T)$ ensemble?**

Comment: What does 'P' stand for? If you mean pressure - 'p' (lowercase) is a more common notation (in general, except for the temperature - lowercase for intensive variables, while uppercase for extensive).

Comment: @Piot: I edited to clarify, $P$ is pressure. I've seen it both lowercase and uppercase depending on textbooks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you have only one species of particles then working with $(\mu,p,T)$ ensemble does not make  sense, as its thermodynamic potential is $0$.

$$U = TS -pV + \mu N,$$
so the Legendre transformation in all of its variables (i.e. $S-T$, $V-(-p)$ and $N-\mu$)
$$U[T,p,\mu] = U - TS + pV - \mu N$$
is always zero.

The fact is called [Gibbs-Duhem relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%E2%80%93Duhem_equation), i.e.
$$0 = d(U[T,p,\mu]) = -S dT + V dp - N d\mu.$$

However, if you have more species of particles, you can work with a thermodynamic potential as long as you have at least one extensive variable (e.g. number of one species of particles).

Comment: The Legendre transform is zero because it is implicitly assumed the thermodynamic limit. If one computes the Laplace transform from the NPT ensemble with respect to N or that of the grandcanonical ensemble with respect to V, one finds a non-zero thermodynamic potential.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't see any physical reason to exclude a system that exchanges energy, volume and particles with its surrounding made of the same species of particles: for instance, a gas confined in a elastic and porous box. Such a physical system at thermal equilibrium would be described by the $\mu PT$ ensemble, following Jaynes' derivation of the Gibbs measure or generalizing the derivation of the grandcanonical ensemble from the canonical ensemble to derive the $\mu PT$ ensemble from the grandcanonical. What else would model this physical system? What is wrong in the above derivations?

Comment: What you described is not really a system, is it? It is not bounded in any meaningful way... How would you distinguish between what is and what is not a part of the system in your description?